# Angular 2 and Ionic 3 Lifecycle completion in a Component

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am quite confused with Lifecycles of a component in Angular 2 and Ionic 3.

I have the following component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { MemberService } from '../../services/members/member.service';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {
    originPost: string = "mine";
  profile: any;
  passed_profile: any;
  username: any;
  user_profile: any;
  following_text: string;
  storage: Storage = new Storage();
  // We need to inject AuthService so that we can
  // use it in the view



  constructor(public memberAuth: MemberService, public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams) {
    this.passed_profile = params.get('profile');
    this.storage.get('profile').then(profile => {
      this.user_profile = profile;
    });
  }

  ionViewCanEnter() {
    if(this.passed_profile) {
      this.profile = this.passed_profile;

    } else {
        this.getProfileDetails({username: this.user_profile.username});

    }

    if(this.profile.username != this.user_profile.username) {
      this.following_text = this.profile.is_following ? 'Following' : 'Follow';
    }
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("profile page has loaded")
  }


  getProfileDetails(username) {
    this.memberAuth.get_profile(username).subscribe((profile) => {
      this.profile = profile;
    })
  }
}
```

This code looks great until it gets run then it doesnt run as expected.

As per documentation, Lifecycle in a component is as follows Constructor -> IonViewCanEnter but what happens in my code is that upon entering into the profile page, the constructor is run but before completion, it starts to run the ionViewCanEnter method hence i get an error on my page because some data `this.user_profile` is needed in the ionViewCanEnter method but because the constructor method hasnt finished running its code, then in the ionViewCanEnter `this.user_profile` is empty or nil.

Kinda confused how to ensure that constructor method is completed before going into the ionViewCanEnter method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The life cycle is `Constructor -> IonViewCanEnter`. But in your constructor has an async function. May be it has not completed before `IonViewCanEnter` is runned.
Try to move all code in `IonViewCanEnter` to `ionViewDidEnter`. If it still not works, you should place your code inside `.then` function like that:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.storage.get('profile').then(profile => {
      this.user_profile = profile;
      //Now you can use this.user_profile
      this.profile = this.passed_profile;
      ...
  });
}
```